# Printing a string of text using double quotes

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print(''What is "program"?'')
```

I'm required to use double quotations either 2 apostrophes ('') or 2 quotation marks ("") to print this string, but the quotes on program creates a syntax error. I tried using backslash before the " to ignore them, but that doesn't work either

Comment: So you want to print double quotes? Would this not work: `print(" What is the \"program\"")`?

Comment: That's because `''` is an empty string (two single quotes) followed by an unconcatenated `What is` which it tries to interpret as variables.

Comment: you can use single quotation marks at the start and at the end `print('What is "program"?')`

Comment: I'm trying to do this, print(""What is "program"?"")

Comment: I know I can use single quotes but the task asks me to use double quotes

Answer (score 5):

You have two options for printing double quotes in Python.

- You can use the escape character(`\`) to escape the double quotes, telling Python that they are not "special":

  ```
  print("What is the \"program\"")
  ```
- Or you can take advantage of the fact that *single* quoted strings can contain double quotes and their is no need to escape them:

  ```
  print('What is the "program"')
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
print("What is \"program\"?")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Triple Quote is the most easiest way without remembering where to put extra /
Try This:

```
print('''What is "program"?''')
```